# Dynamically change table checkbox status in primeng

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-table

I'm new to priming. I'm using a primenng table. Where by default some checkboxes are checked by using [(selection)]. But now I want to dynamically update some checkboxes based on a few checkbox clicks.
example 1,
Suppose there are 3 rows with checkboxes which are all unselected. If I select the row no 2 checkbox, the row no 1 checkbox will automatically get selected.
example 2,
Suppose there are 4 rows where 1 & 2 checkboxes are by default selected. Now if I select 3, 4 will be automatically selected. But if I unselect 2, 1 will be automatically unselected.
Can someone please help me resolve the issue? I want a solution, using p-tableCheckbox

tried primeng selection, ngmodel

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `(onRowSelect)="onRowSelect($event)" (onRowUnselect)="onRowUnselect($event)"` events and add there your logic.

[ngPrime Table API Events](https://primeng.org/table#api.table.events)